# Entity Framework - Load/Remove Existing Entity by Multiple Critereon

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

All,

I purchased The Julia Lerman book *[Programming DbContext](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1449312969)* and looking through the examples, I do not see any way to load an existing entity with more than 1 search parameter:

**Example from Book:**

```
using (var context = new BreakAwayContext())
{
   var bay = (from d in context.Destinations
              where d.Name =="Wine Glass Bay"
              select d).Single();

   context.Destinations.Remove(bay);
   context.SaveChanges();
}
```

What if I wanted to find all destinations `where d.Name == "Wine Glass Bay" AND d.State = "CA"`? I would rather not execute raw SQL if not necessary. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C# use the `&&` logical "AND" operator:

```
from d in context.Destinations
where d.Name  == "Wine Glass Bay" 
   && d.State == "CA"
select d
```